# Freemarker ruby script template issue

Tags: ruby, escaping, typeerror, freemarker, expansion

So I am trying to run a ruby script and I have string expansion sections that are being mistaken for freemarker expressions, for example:

```
puts "Foo bar baz quux #{@awesome}"
```

In ruby the #{} is valid ruby, and I need Freemarker to ignore it. According to the [documentation](https://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_string), I can escape lie this:

```
#\{@awesome}
```

But that leaves the backslash in the final output. I tried to do this:

```
#{r"#{@awesome"}}
```

But I get an exception saying that a number was expected... According to the docs, this should produce a literal '#{@awesome}'

What gives? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
${r"#{@awesome"}}
```

Your attempt gives error because FreeMarker's `#{...}` only accepts numbers.

Comment: That was my guess (It occurred to me once i posted this question) but i wanted to be sure